# VB.net program hangs when asked to read .txt

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I am attempting to read a .txt file that I successfully wrote with a separate program, but I keep getting the program stalling (aka no input/output at all, like it had an infinite loop or something). I get the message "A", but no others.

I've seen a lot of threads on sites like this one that list all sorts of creative ways to read from a file, but every guide I have found wants me to change the code between Msgbox A and Msgbox D. None of them change the result, so I'm beginning to think that the issue is actually with how I'm pointing out the file's location. There was one code (had something to do with `Dim objReader As New System.IO.TextReader(FileLoc)`), but when I asked for a read of the file I got the file's address instead. That's why I suspect I'm pointing to the .txt wrong. There is one issue...

I have absolutely no idea how to do this, if what I've done is wrong.

I've attached at the end the snippet of code (with every single line of extraneous data ripped out of it).

If it matters, the location of the actual program is in the "G01-Cartography" folder.

```
  Private Sub GameMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   LoadMap("Map_Cygnus.txt")
 End Sub

  Private Sub LoadMap(FileLoc As String)
   FileLoc = "C:\Users\Adam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\G01-Cartography\Maps\" + FileLoc
    MsgBox("A")
    Using File As New StreamReader(FileLoc)
        MsgBox("B")
        Dim WholeMap = File.ReadLine()
        MsgBox("C")
    End Using
    MsgBox("D")
  End Sub
```

Comment: Using MsgBox() is a very dangerous way to debug code.  It causes re-entrancy, your Shown event will for example fire before Load is completed.   You need to learn to use breakpoints in the debugger.  And the debugger's Call Stack window to find out why your code hangs.  Essential skills to learn, take the time.

Comment: Alright, in that case, what is 're-entrancy', what is 'call stack', and isn't the whole point of the load section to load things? If you could find some links explaining this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It is a Very Bad Thing.  Focus your energy, learn how to use the debugger first.

Comment: @Rettro Where does it hang? What msgboxes are displayed?

Comment: Please use `File.close()` (To close the StreamReader)

Comment: @MahadevMalkar: Not required with `Using`.

Comment: @mikek3332002 I get "A", but not the others. Accidentally cut that info out when I was phrasing the question, added back into original post.

Comment: @HansPassant Sure, but how? All I'm getting out of you is a list of things I don't know how to do, can you offer any advice on how to actually learn them?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the correct methods/objects according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw67h925.aspx). 
*Your code runs for me in an new VB console app(.net 4.5)*

A different approach then MSGBOXs would be to use [Debug.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z9k5ydz(v=vs.100).aspx) or [Console.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

- If MSGBOX A shows but not B, then the problem is in constructing the stream reader.

  - Probably you are watching the application for output but the debugger(visual studio) has stopped the application on that line, with an exception.  eg File not found, No Permission, using a http uri...
- If MSGBOX C doesn't show then problem is probably that the file has problems being read.

  - Permissions?
  - Does it have a Line of Text?
  - Is the folder 'online'
- If MSGBOX D **shows**, but nothing happens then you are doing nothing with `WholeMap`

  - See what is displayed if you rewite `MsgBox("C")` to `Debug.WriteLine("Read " + WholeMap)`

Comment: I accidentally cut that line out there... "A" shows but the other three do not. Currently trying to figure out the debugger. I can open the txt file and it does have data in it, a single line of numbers and symbols (which is what I put there)

Answer (score 1):

What does running this show you in the debugger? Can you open the Map_Cygnus.txt file in Notepad? Set a breakpoint on the first line and run the program to see what is going on.

```
Private BaseDirectory As String = "C:\Users\Adam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\G01-Cartography\Maps\"

Private Sub GameMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim WholeMap = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(BaseDirectory, "Map_Cygnus.txt"))
    Debug.Print("Size Of Map: {0}", WholeMap.Length)
End Sub
```

Comment: What it shows in the debugger... Dunno. Trying to learn how to use that now. The txt does have the proper data in it, and I can see it when I open with notepad. It may be a few days but when I figure out the debugger I'll get back to you.

Comment: In the meantime, you can run the code above and see what shows up in your immediate window (the Debug.Print statement will add a line there). To see the immediate window, select Debug->Windows->Immediate.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions. Firstly, use `Option Strict On`, it will help you to avoid headaches down the road.

The code to open the file is correct. In addition to avoiding using `MsgBox()` to debug and instead setting breakpoints or using `Debug.WriteLine()`, wrap the subroutine in a `Try...Catch` exception.

```
Private Sub GameMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadMap("Map_Cygnus.txt")
End Sub

Private Sub LoadMap(FileLoc As String)
    Try
        FileLoc = "C:\Users\Adam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\G01-Cartography\Maps\" + FileLoc
        MsgBox("A")
        Using File As New StreamReader(FileLoc)
            MsgBox("B")
            Dim WholeMap = File.ReadLine()         'dimming a variable inside a block like this means the variable only has scope while inside the block
            MsgBox("C")
        End Using
        MsgBox("D")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Note that you normally should only catch whatever exceptions you expect, but I generally catch everything while debugging things like this.

I would also like to point out that you are only reading one line out of the file into the variable `WholeMap`. That variable loses scope as soon as the `End Using` line is hit, thereby losing the line you just read from the file. I'm assuming that you have the code in this way because it seems to be giving you trouble reading from it, but thought I would point it out anyway.

```
Public Class GameMain
    Private WholeMap As String = ""

    Private Sub GameMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadMap("Map_Cygnus.txt")
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadMap(FileLoc As String)
        Try
            FileLoc = "C:\Users\Adam\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\G01-Cartography\Maps\" + FileLoc
            Using File As New StreamReader(FileLoc)
                WholeMap = File.ReadLine()         'dimming the variable above will give all of your subs inside class Form1 access to the contents of it (note that I've removed the Dim command here)
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I actually do have option strict on, it's just much higher in the code so it didn't make it into this snippet.

Comment: (Apparently you have to shift-enter to get a new line, enter just posts it and you can only edit for 5 mins. Who knew.)

I'm trying to put in that sort of debug line stuff now, but it may take a bit to figure out. As I'm sure you can tell I don't do this for a living. If you can point me towards some guide for that stuff I'd appreciate it. 

The file SHOULD only have one line, it's a stream of coordinates ("1,3.5,3.16,3" etc), but I was unaware that the data would be lost when the using closed. Honestly I don't know what using does, it's just the least failure-ey method I've found so far.

Comment: the Using command simply lets you open a resource such as a file and when execution hits End Using it closes the file and handles the resources for you. It's not that Using loses the data, it's that you are Diming the WholeMap variable inside the using block. I've edited my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Also, as far as debugging why the file is giving you trouble, set a breakpoint inside the `LoadMap()` method by right-clicking, selecting Breakpoint, and Insert Breakpoint, then run the code. When it hits the line you set a breakpoint on, use F11 (default) to let the code run line by line. I'm betting that with the try catch wrapped around it, it will show you what is causing it to hang/crash.